# Confusion about android version on Samsung phone

Tags: google-play-store, android-versions

I have for a lot of years been playing this game, 'Wordz', on my Samsung A21S, but suddenly it did not work properly.
I removed it and wanted to reinstall, but now it says it does not work on my device(?)

I love this game, and I seriously think about getting a new phone, also since I believe other apps may stop working in the future (old phone).

So, of course I'd like to check the version needed for this app to work, and there the confusion starts.

On Play.google.com it says it need Android 4.0.3 and up.
My phone says it has Android version 12.
Something doesn't fit here, but I don't get it. I must look at the wrong numbers somehow, but I can not find out what to look for.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Pictures instead of a thousand words:

**Play.google.com:**

[image: Play.google.com:]

**Settings, Samsung A21S:**

[image: Settings, Samsung A21S:]

Comment: Version 4.0.50 is the version of the App itself. You can not install this app because it is too old (released May 2020). Since a few years Google requires apps to be updated about every 1-2 years, otherwise the app will not be available to new users on new devices: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878

Comment: Robert's comment is likely correct regarding the app being "too old". That said, you may find and try the APK for installation from somewhere else.

Comment: @Robert so it's not my phone but the app that's too old?
If I get this correct, a new phone would not solve it, it's Fugo that need to update the app (which is unlikely), and then it would be available to me again?

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the advice, I'm not very experienced in this, but it sounds - risky. Am I not right about that?

Comment: Yes, the app is too old and the developer needs to update it, but it's Play Store that blocks the installation, not the device (yet, [until Android 14](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-14-block-outdated-apps/)). As for APK, it may be risky depending on the source, but that's the only alternative. (Btw, it seems you forgot to @ping the commenters, thus we didn't get notified. I edited and fixed your previous comments)

Comment: @MadsAggerholm Do you use the same Google account on the old phone and the new phone? If you have the old phone with the app installed you can extract the APK file transfer it to the new phone and then install it manually on the new phone. This would would reduce the risk down to zero. I know that the open source Amaze file manager can extract apps https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks! I didn't know you should/could /@ping the commenters. I hope I have done it right this time(?)

Comment: @Robert, unfortunately I do no longer have my old-old phones, this is already an old phone... :-)

Answer (score -1):

Clear Google Play’s cache and data
Open the Settings app.
Apps & notifications > Sell all apps > Google Play Store.
Storage > Clear data > Clear cache.
Try downloading or opening the app again.

Comment: I am confused, what is this an answer to